# How can one customize cursor movement shortcuts in Texpad editor?

Tags: texpad

I'm running Texpad 1.8.3 and at the moment ctrl+F moves the cursor one character to the right and ctrl+B moves it one character to the left. I'd like to modify this to make it consistent with commands I'm used to from a different editor. The Texpad website is surprisingly unhelpful on this front and I can't see any option for this particular type of customization in Texpad preferences. Any help/suggestions would be greatly appreciated.